# Disable Infinispan Clustering in Wildfly 10.1

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly, ejb-3.1, infinispan

I have two Wildfly 10.1.0 Final server running on the same machine. Each has the same application deployed but for different clients.
Each server is also configured to use Inifinispan 8.2.4 as a second level cache.

Now, here is the situation: the first server starts and it comes to the following log entries:

```
2017-04-19 06:25:29,414 INFO  (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel infinispan-hibernate-cluster
2017-04-19 06:25:36,166 INFO  (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.viewAccepted) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel infinispan-hibernate-cluster: [XXX-56490|0] (1) [XXX-56490]
2017-04-19 06:25:36,170 INFO  (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded) ISPN000079: Channel infinispan-hibernate-cluster local address is XXX-56490, physical addresses are [127.0.0.1:7800]
```

This is the log from starting the second server:

```
2017-04-19 06:26:16,869 INFO  (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel infinispan-hibernate-cluster
2017-04-19 06:26:17,800 INFO  (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.viewAccepted) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel infinispan-hibernate-cluster: [XXX-56490|1] (2) [XXX-56490, XXX-29707]
2017-04-19 06:26:17,807 INFO  (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded) ISPN000079: Channel infinispan-hibernate-cluster local address is XXX-29707, physical addresses are [127.0.0.1:7801]
```

At the same time as the second server starts, this happens at the first server:

```
2017-04-19 06:26:17,761 INFO  (Incoming-2,XXX-56490) [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.viewAccepted) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel infinispan-hibernate-cluster: [XXX-56490|1] (2) [XXX-56490, XXX-29707]
```

plus several messages like the following, looks like one for each cached entity:

```
2017-04-19 06:26:18,321 INFO  (remote-thread--p11-t1) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER.broadcastRebalanceStart) ISPN000310: Starting cluster-wide rebalance for cache XXX.ear/XXX.jar#XXX.Section, topology CacheTopology{id=2, rebalanceId=2, currentCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (1)[XXX-56490: 256]}, pendingCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (2)[XXX-56490: 126, XXX-29707: 130]}, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[XXX-56490, XXX-29707]}
2017-04-19 06:26:18,327 INFO  (remote-thread--p11-t1) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER.log) [Context=XXX.ear/XXX.jar#XXX.Section][Scope=XXX-56490]ISPN100002: Started local rebalance
2017-04-19 06:26:18,334 INFO  (transport-thread--p13-t23) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER.log) [Context=XXX.ear/XXX.jar#XXX.Section][Scope=XXX-56490]ISPN100003: Finished local rebalance
2017-04-19 06:26:18,420 INFO  (remote-thread--p11-t1) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER.log) [Context=XXX.ear/XXX.jar#XXX.Section][Scope=XXX-29707]ISPN100003: Finished local rebalance
2017-04-19 06:26:18,422 INFO  (remote-thread--p11-t1) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER.endRebalance) ISPN000336: Finished cluster-wide rebalance for cache XXX.ear/XXX.jar#XXX.Section, topology id = 2
```

**I would like to disable that behaviour completely and have the two instances running without sharing information.**

I found in the infinispan-core-8.2.4.Final.jar module three default config files (jgroups-tcp, jgroups-google, jgroups-ec2) containing a port set to 7800.

I checked several documentation already but couldn't find any answer.

Maybe I need to disable any clustering feature in wildfly directly? Is it activated by default?

This is the used standalone.xml from the wildfly/standalone/configuration/ folder:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.2">

<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.request-controller"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.security.manager"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
</extensions>


<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="XXXXX-system-realm">
            <authentication>
                <jaas name="XXXXX-login"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <audit-log>
        <formatters>
            <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
        </formatters>
        <handlers>
            <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
        </handlers>
        <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
            <handlers>
                <handler name="file"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
    </audit-log>
    <management-interfaces>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
            <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
    <access-control provider="simple">
        <role-mapping>
            <role name="SuperUser">
                <include>
                    <user name="$local"/>
                </include>
            </role>
        </role-mapping>
    </access-control>
</management>

<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <some logging config>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:1.0">
        <default-job-repository name="in-memory"/>
        <default-thread-pool name="batch"/>
        <job-repository name="in-memory">
            <in-memory/>
        </job-repository>
        <thread-pool name="batch">
            <max-threads count="10"/>
            <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
        </thread-pool>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:bean-validation:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/XXXXXDS" pool-name="PostgreSQLPool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/XXXXX</connection-url>
                <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>postgresql-9.4.1209.jar</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>XXXXX</user-name>
                    <password>XXXXX</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
        <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
        <concurrent>
            <context-services>
                <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
            </context-services>
            <managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
            </managed-thread-factories>
            <managed-executor-services>
                <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="5000"/>
            </managed-executor-services>
            <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="3000"/>
            </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
        </concurrent>
        <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:/XXXXXDS" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0">
        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
        <mdb>
            <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"/>
            <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
        </mdb>
        <pools>
            <bean-instance-pools>
                <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-worker-pools" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-cpu-count" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
            </bean-instance-pools>
        </pools>
        <caches>
            <cache name="simple"/>
            <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
        </caches>
        <passivation-stores>
            <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
        </passivation-stores>
        <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
            <data-stores>
                <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </data-stores>
        </timer-service>
        <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <thread-pools>
            <thread-pool name="default">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </thread-pools>
        <default-security-domain value="XXXXX-login"/>
        <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
        <log-system-exceptions value="true"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
        <worker name="default"/>
        <buffer-pool name="default"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
        <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
            <local-cache name="default">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="concurrent">
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:4.0">
        <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
        <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
        <default-workmanager>
            <short-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </short-running-threads>
            <long-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </long-running-threads>
        </default-workmanager>
        <cached-connection-manager/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
        <remoting-connector/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
        <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
        <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
        </mail-session>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:3.0">
        <endpoint/>
        <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="XXXXX-system-realm"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:request-controller:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
        <deployment-permissions>
            <maximum-set>
                <permission class="java.security.AllPermission"/>
            </maximum-set>
        </deployment-permissions>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="XXXXX-login" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                        <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex"/>
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/XXXXXDS"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT u.password AS PASSWD FROM XXXXX"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT DISTINCT f.name AS ROLEID, 'Roles' AS Roles FROM XXXXX=?"/>
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jaspitest" cache-type="default">
                <authentication-jaspi>
                    <login-module-stack name="dummy">
                        <login-module code="Dummy" flag="optional"/>
                    </login-module-stack>
                    <auth-module code="Dummy"/>
                </authentication-jaspi>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:3.0">
        <core-environment>
            <process-id>
                <uuid/>
            </process-id>
        </core-environment>
        <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
        <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:3.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" redelivery-delay="5000" max-delivery-attempts="3" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>
</profile>

<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8082}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

And this is the persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="XXX">

        <jta-data-source>java:/XXXDS</jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <!--<shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>-->

        <class>XXXXX</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="100"/>

            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>

            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.strategy" value="LRU"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.wake_up_interval" value="1000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.max_entries" value="10000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.lifespan" value="-1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.max_idle" value="10000"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any hints?

Best regards,
Manuel

Comment: Do you use `standalone-full-ha.xml` profile?

Comment: @FedericoSierra added the standalone.xml and persistence.xml

Comment: Wildfly cluster doesn't use the `standalone.xml` configuration file, rather it uses the `domain.xml` configuration file (both master and slave servers).

Comment: @BuhakeSindi the server uses the standalone.xml file in the ./standalone/configuration/ folder

Comment: according to section 7 Caching Modes at https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-infinispan there exists a localcache but I don't know how to configure that

Comment: You are not starting it in standalone mode. Clarify how you are starting these servers? BTW unrelated but I'd consider running both apps on the same WildFly node, that would allow you to use resources in a more efficient way and I'm not just referring to memory.

Comment: @Sanne "sudo ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone.xml", I also deleted any other xml file in that folder and the wildfly/domain folder as well.
plus, as said above, I change things in that very xml-file and it is reflected while starting

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a port conflict, not a cluster.

In your standalone.xml, socket-binding-group, instead of define, for example, http port 8082, you can define:

```
port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:200}"
```

and restore default ports in http and other services. After this, http port will be 8080 + 200 = 8280, and the same for others sockets.

Comment: if there is port conflict, won't the services start at all ?

Comment: there is no port conflict, look at the addresses the JGroup adds (127.0.0.1:7800 and 127.0.0.1:7801)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple standalone.xml examples in the configuration folder. The normal standalone.xml does not include the modules required for for infinispan clustering.

The non-clustered base configuration defines the infinispan caches all as "local-cache" (compare: replicated-cache or distributed-cache).

If you do not require additional functionality included in the standalone-ha or standalone-full-ha, then just revert to the original version.

For more information on configuring individual subsystems, have a look at:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Subsystem+configuration

Comment: can you point to the above stated and used standalone.xml where I can turn this off?

I didn't change anything with the caches intentionally though I am very clueless how this works exactly...

Comment: Yeah, I did not look into your standalone.xml in detail. Now that I did and diffed it with mine, I think you might have another problem: are you sure you are starting wildfly with the standalone.xml you posted? The "-c" parameter can be used to reference a different configuration file. And everything in your log messages would indicate to me that the "standalone-ha.xml" is being used. JGroups for example, is not even included in the posted config, but clearly active. Might check how the server is starting.

Comment: pretty sure, anything I change in that xml is reflected in the server.
the logging outputs also

sun.java.command = /usr/local/XXX-11b/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/local/XXX-11b/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/XXX-11b -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/XXX-11b/standalone

There might be a infinispan-configs.xml in one of the hibernate/infinispan modules, but that one again must be referenced by or reference something configured in the standalone.xml

Comment: it is stated here https://developer.jboss.org/thread/243428 that "private Infinispan instance will create its own channel from the default jgroups configuration shipped within the infinispan-core jar from the org.infinispan module"